# How can I generate a Delphi string literal escaped the same as the Evaluate\Modify dialog?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I need to generate strings as displayed when invoking the IDE's Evaluate\Modify on a string value. The string as displayed in that window can be used directly in Delphi code.

I am writing string constant literals to an include file that is used in Delphi code.

These string constants contain characters that are printable, non-printable, I also have characters in the $80-$A0 range where WideString and AnsiString ordinals don't match (e.g. `Assert(Char(#$96) <> Char(#$0096))`, even though `Assert($96 = $0096)`). I could make my constants all escaped characters, but it will affect readability of the rest of the text.

Here is a manufactured case exemplifying a problematic string. You can see that Evaluate\Modify handles the problem cases correctly while leaving printable sections as quoted strings.

```
const 
  AString: String  = 'W'#$0096'~ '#$1C;
```

Please note that `QuotedString` cannot work. It won't generate strings to represent escaped sequences, it would merely quote the string and and have escaped sequences as the actual characters they represent. The goal here is to produce a string that can be used in code.

Comment: I suspect TParser can be used, but I don't know for sure

Comment: Doesn't sound like the sort of thing TParser would be useful for, but ISTR Delphi includes example debug visualizers that might show how to do it.

Comment: @JasperSchellingerhout: What you want to do is the opposite of parsing Pascal code.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand you are correct.

Comment: Something like this? https://privat.rejbrand.se/PascalStringLiteral.html

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I just had to escape the quote `if C = '''' then Result := Result + C;` and your function passes all my tests. Thank you

Comment: @JasperSchellingerhout: Oh, sorry, I completely forgot that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't match the IDE's implementation precisely, but should be a very decent start:

```pascal
function MakeStringLiteral(const AString: string): string;
begin
  var InText := False;
  Result := '';
  for var c in AString do
    if C.IsControl then
    begin
      if InText then
      begin
        Result := Result + '''';
        InText := False;
      end;
      Result := Result + '#$' + IntToHex(Ord(C));
    end
    else
    begin
      if not InText then
        Result := Result + '''';
      Result := Result + C;
      if C = '''' then
        Result := Result + '''';
      InText := True;
    end;
  if InText then
    Result := Result + '''';
  if Result.IsEmpty then
    Result := '''''';
end;
```

The rules are simple:

1. Runs of non-control characters are surrounded by apostrophes.
2. Apostrophes in such runs are escaped.
3. Control characters are written as hex escapes.
4. The empty string is `''`.